# CSS3PIE's htc file is not downloaded by IE9

Tags: asp.net, iis, internet-explorer-9, css3pie

I'm using the http://css3pie.com/ library in an ASP.NET 4.0 web application which allows IE 6-9 to render CSS3 decoration features.
IE9 doesn't download the pie.htc file (404 error). It's OK with IE8.
On my IIS 7.5 webserver, the MIME type for .htc is set to text/x-component.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have the same issue.  It's not possible to replicate through a fiddle as I think it's to do with the way the htc file is served through IIS 7.5. The MIME type is set correctly, but for some reason loading the .htc file as a behaviour in CSS forces IE9 to redirect to a 404.  Baffled!

Answer (score 0):

That's not a lot to go on.  Could be that you're using relative paths that aren't being interpreted identically.  Could be some other script on your page, like http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=986
Maybe if you had a fiddle or a URL to look at we could help you.